# Getting value from a pointer parameter of a function in C

Tags: c, pointers, parameters

as I am starting to study at university we are learning how to write in C and we got to the point where I've learned that I can use pointers as function parameters but what they haven't told us is how to get the value from it. I am not able as a person who doesn't know about C as much, to come up with other solution than use two parameters (one as pointer to the variable and other as value. See the example which is not real code but it's just for purpose of demonstration:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv []) {

     int a;
     addNumber(&a);


}

void addNumber(int * a) {
     *a = *a + 1; // this obviously does not work
}
```

Any input would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that may be closer to what you are looking for:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void increment(int *a, int *b)
{
    *a = *a + *b;
}

int main(void)
{
    int sum = 5;
    int increment_by = 7;
    printf("sum: %d, increment_by: %d\n", sum, increment_by);
    increment(&sum, &increment_by);
    printf("sum: %d, increment_by: %d\n", sum, increment_by);

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
$ ./bar
sum: 5, increment_by: 7
sum: 12, increment_by: 7
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't realize it would make such a difference.

Comment: So others can learn - what part of my answer made a difference for you?

Comment: The inicialization, From you example and by comparing it to my code I immediately realized that I forgot to inicialize the variables and I didn't realize it would cause the problem. Rookie mistake. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Only one major thing: You forgot to initialize `a`. Otherwise, it looks fine.

```
 int a = 0;
 addNumber(&a);
```

The only other thing is that you're missing the return statement in `main`.

Comment: `a` is not initialized, maybe that's why the OP thinks it doesn't work?

Comment: and `a` is missing an initialization value.

Comment: And C99, regrettably, sanctions omitting that return - to follow C++98 which also sanctions the omission of the return from `main()`.  The effect is as if you wrote `return 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

It will work. It will work better if you initialise `a`, to some value.